# Is it possible to create a Nuget Package from a .NET Core Application?

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package

I was wondering, before I get started with making a new Blazor app, if it's possible to create/format a Nuget package (.nupkg) from a .NET Core 3.1 web application?

Answer (score 0):

You can place part of your application in a class library and create a nuget package for that.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: Not exactly what I was hoping for, but good to know I can do this.